# Ionic Angular Firestore get field value

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a field value from a document and display it in the html file. How do you get a field value? For example displaying the username. Below is a picture of how the data is stored and my code so far. The error that I am getting is

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even
>   number of segments

I believe that I am just getting the data in the wrong way.

[image]

**Home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';    
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Profile } from './../../models/profile';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  prodcollection: AngularFirestore<Profile> = this.afs.collection('profiles');

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
        this.prodcollection = this.afs.doc(`${data.uid}`).valueChanges();
      }else {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <p>Username: {{prodcollection.username}} </p>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using firestore you have to subscribe to the data first and put it in a object and then you can use the data.

```
prodcollection: AngularFirestore<Profile>;
profile = {} as Profile;

this.prodcollection = this.afs.collection('profiles').doc(`${data.uid}`).valueChanges();

this.prodcollection.subscribe(
profile => this.profile = profile);
```